# CSS Header Issue

Tags: css, html, web

When the browser gets stretched from its width, the header doesn't move, but the content of the page does. It's driving me nuts. If you stretch it far enough, the banner eventually ends. IE: it doesnt repeat further the banner.

Any advice? I'm not sure which part of the source code would control this. I'll put the CSS up and if needed, I can throw up part of my HTML.

[Image Examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bean.jpg)

[Web](http://lssclan.urldownload.com/anth/)

Comment: It would help if you highlighted the header parts of your CSS... Are you making sure to set `width: 100%` for the banner? What about `margin: 0px auto` to center the header content of the page?

Comment: ^ The #mast is the main bar on top and #primary-nav is the words/links

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle and just show us what you're working with so we can actually fix this? Too much speculation on our end... http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: ^ I added the website to look at live.

I've tried changing a bunch of CSS and fiddling. I just cant figure it out.

Comment: OK! Progress! I got the stuff centered, but now the banner wont expand. The banner is located in header #mast.short h1 a, however the space constraints seem to be messing with it in #mast h1 a.

Comment: Why not just keep the banner where it was before? :-)

Comment: Because the banner was not stretching properly. Still isn't.

Comment: Set the background of the `sizefix` div to the background for the banner and then change the height of the element to get the effect you're looking for. I'm sure you can change some settings as to if the overflow is hidden or adjust the margins and positioning of other relevant elements, you'll get what you're looking for. I just got the banner to repeat just by changing what I told you in the Chrome Inspector so despite the fact that the structure of your current page isn't very conducive to the effect you're going for, it can be done.

Comment: ^ I'd like to know where you made those changes because I cannot get them to work.
Right now the banner is a tiny square behind my logo and name. If I set the width, it only stretches to the right but completely leaves the left margin empty.

I went back to the things you said earlier and I already have margin: 0px auto set. I also have width: 100%.

As for "sizefix" div, please elaborate as I don't recall making a div like that.

Comment: I got it ~partially~ there. Its just that left margin that is weird. And weirder still is that the right side there is a "sliver" of banner that doesnt render unless you pull the page

Comment: Did you write this code yourself or pull it from somewhere? When I view the source of your page, there is a `sizefix` div that wraps the `<header />` tag.

Comment: The framework itself I pulled from some repository. I forget the name exactly at the moment, however if crucial, I can find it.

I fixed the right side margin by increasing the width 100% to 200%. A friend of mine pointed it out.
However, now I just have the left side margin that is still a big empty block if I stretch the browser window out to the right.

Do you know of any way I could basically tell my mast banner to expand to the right? or do I need to just offset it to the right by a lot?

Comment: Ok everything seems good now.

The main issue remaining is that the image "Anthony Barranco" is now suddenly overshadowing my text links. In other words, you can't click them. The image Anthony Barranco has a .png height in order to get it to float above the text. That is making the links unclickable now, when they were before. Odd.

Comment: Check this out to fix the links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a large combination of difference changes that were answers. Basically it came down to a number of width changes.

If I set width 100% in one place, it had to go in multiple ones because the entire mast div was nested divs. Also, to get the banner to expand further to right, it had to be 200% for width.

The proper code is reflected in the website, at least for my solution.
Thank you everyone, and specifically TMan.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your markup (which would be helpful to share), it looks like line 9 is your problem:

```
header#mast{margin:0 0 0 0px;width:1200px;position:fixed;top:0px;left:0%;z-index:100;}
```

Update it to:

```
header#mast{margin:0 0 0 -600px;width:1200px;position:fixed;top:0px;left:50%;z-index:100;}
```

(Note the `left:50%` and `-600px` left margin (half the width of the element).

Comment: Ok, now it moves with the text. However, there is a huge gap to the banner to the right. If I increase the -600px to like -900px, that closes the gap. HOWEVER, now all my buttons and title is off centered. Does that mean my other CSS needs to be readjusted?

Comment: Can you please share a working version of the page, as is, from some URL?  It would make these issues far easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: http://lssclan.urldownload.com/anth/

Thank you for the assistance ahead of time, really appreciated. Its killing me. :p

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your `#mast` and `#primary-nav' elements in a`div`that has a style of`margin: 0px auto` this should cause everything to continue to center with the rest of the page as your expand the window.

As far as the banner ending is concerned, add the style `width: 100%` to the element that is responsible for it for the resulting infinite expansion as you widen the window.

**EDIT**

Since you've added the website, put the contents of the header in the following tag:

`<div class="container container-twelve">...</div>`

This will center your image, text, and links.

Comment: if you mean
"header#mast.short h1 a{width:100%;height:170px;background:url(images/header.png);"

That still treats the 100 as px.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right tag then to manipulate the width? Any time you have `width: 100%`, that should never be taken as px unless 100px is the max width of the parent container.

Comment: yeah. And I tried it in other tags too just to see if it would change, but nothing did.